# Was "Pale Blue Eyes" an inspiration for "Burning Chrome"?

Tags: music, cyberpunk, william-gibson, sprawl-trilogy, burning-chrome

Neil Gaiman, in a piece for Lou Reed written for *[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2013/oct/28/neil-gaiman-lou-reed-sandman)* in 2013 and reprinted in his non-fiction collection *[The View from the Cheap Seats](https://books.google.gr/books?id=YNOKCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT365&lpg=PT365&dq=burning%20chrome%20pale%20blue%20eyes&source=bl&ots=0JF-bmXZ2O&sig=ACfU3U2NFM_woFd58W9g4ITuatNo9DiPig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjzeHY5eTiAhXDDOwKHbM9B5EQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, writes:

> I would see Lou's songs surface in the stories I read. William Gibson wrote a short story called Burning Chrome, which is his take on a Velvet Underground song called Pale Blue Eyes.

I have been a Gibson fan for ages, and although I am well aware that he loves and has been influenced by The Velvet Underground and Lou Reed, I have never heard that claim before, neither have I been able to find any reference or corroboration.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly be the case.  Rikki wasn't married, for one, and was practically a MacGuffin for a heist story except at the end.  Plus neither Rikki (amber to brown) or Chrome (grey) have blue eyes.

Comment: If somebody wants to tweet Gibson a link to this question, that might be the best way to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @Buzz have already done so, no reply yet - https://twitter.com/desertnaut/status/1139290990487977989

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly correct, although probably not definitely demonstrable based on existing publicly available information.  Although I cannot find any specific statement from Gibson that the key character of Rikki was inspired by "Pale Blue Eyes," but he has made some allusions that do possibly point in this direction.

The first piece of evidence is Gibson's statement that he owes a great artistic debt to the Velvet Underground.  For example, in [this interview](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/arts/english/currentstudents/undergraduate/modules/en361fantastika/bibliography/1.8gibson_w.1991interview_by_larry_mccaffery.pdf) (included in the book *[Conversations with Willliam Gibson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt6wrskg)*):

> **Larry McCaffery:**  There are so many references to rock music and   television in your work that it sometimes seems your writing is as much influenced by MTV as by literature.  What impact have other media had on your sensibility?
>
> **William   Gibson:** Probably more than fiction. The trouble with "influence" questions is that they're usually framed to encourage you to talk about your writing as if you grew up in a world circumscribed by books.  I've been influenced by Lou Reed, for instance, as much as I've been by an "fiction" writer.  I was going to use a quote from an old Velvet Underground song—"Watch out for worlds behind you" (from "Saturday Morning")—as an epigraph of *Neuromancer*.

Of course, this does not concern "Burning Chrome" specifically, but it does attest to the important influence Gibson felt from the Velvet Underground early in his writing career.

Another statement, in which Gibson specifically relates his origin as a science fiction writer to a scene with "blue eyes."  [Responding](https://twitter.com/GreatDismal/status/1015243334858637312) to this tweet,

> Rockets to Mars, digitized consciousness, underground bunkers—these are all methods of separating themselves from the broader population. Of survival for them, and not for us. And it only gets weirder from there.

Gibson had this to say,

> My career as an sf writer basically started from assuming this. “And, for an instant, she stared directly into those soft blue eyes and knew, with an instinctive mammalian certainty, that the exceedingly rich were no longer even remotely human.” -Count Zero

So although that specific quote did not make it into print until *Count Zero*, Gibson was evidently captivated by the idea of such eyes at a much earlier date—right from the beginning of his SF-writing career, and "Burning Chrome" was among his earliest work.

Moreover, textual references to "pale eyes" [crop of repeatedly](https://www.google.com/search?q=gibson%20%22pale%20eyes%22) in Gibson's writing; pale eyes were clearly an evocative image for him.  Moreover, the nature of their eyes—real or artificial—was an important element in the description and development for the first two female leads in his *Sprawl* stories—Rikki and Molly.

Taken in aggregate, this suggests that Gaiman's statement has a pretty good chance of being correct.  Perhaps this was a more specific fact that Gibson has mentioned to Gaiman privately, giving more detail that Gibson has in any public venues.

Comment: Thanx. Was already aware of these, and I devoted some time yesterday to go through *Conversations*, to no avail. If this is *not* the case (i.e. the answer is negative), I suspect Gibson will not reply to my tweet, since it will sound rather awkward for Gaiman...